# Does ExpressionEngine need unique username?

Tags: unique, expressionengine

I am in the process of importing data from another application to ExpressionEngine. I know that EE expects screen_names to be unique as of Sept 2012.

The question is whether I have to make the username unique too or if I can use a combination of first name and last name (e.g. "johndoe") risking that there might be more then one "john doe" in the imported data.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: If you haven't already, best to ask this question on the new [StackExchange EE Beta](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, username must be unique. In total, `username`, `screen_name`, and `email` all must be unique for a successful import using EE's member import utility.

This is not documented but you can confirm this (if you're curious) by looking at the `validate_xml()` method in `system/expressionengine/controllers/cp/tools_utilities.php`.